# window.print() tries to print a page( which is created dynamically) before it finishes rendering

Tags: javascript, settimeout, synchronous

I am trying to print a table in a new window.
The thing is, `print` tries to print before the page is rendered.
I suspect `document.write` is asynchronous.
I tried to use  `document.outerHTML` / `document.innerHTML` instead of `document.write()`, but the CSS/JS files are not being parsed correctly as CSS.
The table has images in cells which are being loaded from cache, also after `window.print()`.

Please, any idea would be helpful.

```js
function printData() {
    let newWin = window.open("");
    styles="";

    //read styles in different page
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(
      document.querySelectorAll("link, style"), 
      function(el){
      styles += (el.outerHTML);
    });

   //DOESNT WORK NOT RENDER STYLES
   // newWin.document.document.querySelector("html").innerHTML=(styles + document.querySelector("table").outerHTML);
    //THIS FINISHES RENDERING AFTER PRINT
      newWin.document.write(styles + document.querySelector("table").outerHTML);

      //DOESNT WORK 
      newWin.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
      if(newWin.document.addEventListener === "loading"){
          newWin.print();
      }
      //DOESNT WORK
      newWin.window.onload= function(){
          newWin.print();
      }

      //WORKS
      setTimeout(function(){
        newWin.print();
        newWin.close();
      }, 2000);
    });
}
```

Comment: Here's something exotic: Attach an onload function to all images. The first thing it does is set the triggering image's attribute "done" to "true". Then it selects on all images that aren't done: $('img[done!="true"]'). If the length is 0, then print.

Comment: I tried to remove all the images still nope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
let printAndClose = '<script>onload = function() { window.print(); window.close(); }</sc' + 'ript>';

newWin.document.write(
  styles +
  document.querySelector("table").outerHTML) +
  printAndClose
);
```

Comment: Very nice thought:
I tried it and it didnt work but I managed to make it work with     let printAndClose = '<script>window.print(); window.close(); </script>';

Comment: Thanks a lot, do you know why document.write( ) behaves asynchronously?

Comment: `document.write` can be called multiple times to build-up a document from pieces.  There's no implicit call to `document.close`, so... that points to another possible solution: you could explicitly call `newWin.document.close()` before calling `newWin.print()`...

Comment: Thanks!! Was just about to ask a question about this when I came across this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) to fire your function since this waits for all of the content of the page to load and is widely supported.

Comment: I am using it       
      //DOESNT WORK
      newWin.window.onload= function(){
          newWin.print();
      }

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the similar issue by appending the following code to the end of `<body>`. It works in IE11, Chrome and Firefox. Calling `window.close()` without wrapping in `setTimeout()` causes IE11 to close window before showing print dialog.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.print();
        setTimeout(function() {window.close();});
    });
</script>
```